# Using vector with structures

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I have problems inside the initialize database function but i can't seem to find out what it is. This program compiles with no errors but always crashes upon execution. Any idea what is wrong inside the initialise_database function?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstddef> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Date
{
int day, month, year; 
}; 


struct Grade
{
int s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6; 
};

struct Student
{
bool free; 
long studentID; 
string fname; 
string sname; 
Date DOB, DOE, DOG;
Grade semester1, semester2;
};

void initialise_database(vector<Student>, int size); // initialize each free variable to free 

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
fstream fin;
char choice_readfile;
int rowcount;

int size;
cout << "Enter number of student:\n";
cin >> size;

vector<Student> BENG;


    do                                          //verify choice to read from file is Y,y or N,n
    {
        cout << "Do you wish to read from file (Y/N)? (file name must be named students.txt)" <<     endl;          //choice for user to read from external file
        cin >> choice_readfile;
            while(cin.fail())     
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(80,'\n');
                cout << "Please Re-Enter choice" << endl;
                cin >> choice_readfile;             // choice to read from file
            }
    }
    while(choice_readfile != 'Y' && choice_readfile != 'y' && choice_readfile != 'N' && choice_readfile != 'n');

    if(choice_readfile == 'Y' || choice_readfile == 'y')
        {
            fin.open("students.txt", ios::in|ios::out); //opens mygrades.txt 
            if(fin.fail())
            {
                cout << "Error occured while opening students.txt" << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            fin.clear();           
            fin.seekg(0);     

            string line;     
            while( getline(fin, line) )       //counts the rows in the external file
                {
                    rowcount++;
                }          

            cout << "Number of rows in file is " << rowcount << endl; 
            cout << size  << " " << rowcount << endl;
        }

size += rowcount;
int i=0;
initialise_database(BENG, size);
return 0;
}

void initialise_database(vector<Student> BENG, int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        BENG[i].free = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with the code that you've shown.

1) A std::vector does not grow in size automatically. To grow the size of the vector, you need to use resize(), push_back(), emplace_back(), or insert() methods. You're not using them. Your vector remains empty. Attempting to access non-existent elements of the vector results in undefined behavior.

2) The std::vector parameter to initialize_database() is being passed by value. This makes a copy of the vector, and any changes to the vector in initialize_database() will not be reflected in the vector that you actually passed to this function.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<Student> BENG;` here you define an **empty** vector. Later on in the function:

```
void initialise_database(vector<Student> BENG, int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        BENG[i].free = false;
    }
}
```

You access fields with indices up to `size` in this vector. As the vector is empty, any access of an element will fail. Call resize on the vector before calling `initialise_database`. Something like this:

```
size += rowcount;
BENG.resize(size);
initialise_database(BENG, size);
```